# Book repository for storing books that are accessed by ISBN

Tags: java

I want to implement a book repository using a map where books can be added, removed and updated. Books in this repository should be accessed by their ISBN which is an object property. The books should not be edited from the outside of the repository, because if a book’s ISBN is changed from the outside, the ISBN used as key is out of sync with the ISBN of the book.

Another option is to use a list, so I don’t have a key that can be out of sync.

I came up with the following solution.

**Book**:

```java
public class Book {
    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private double price;

    public Book(String isbn, String title, String author, double price) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Book(Book book) {
        this.isbn = book.isbn;
        this.title = book.title;
        this.author = book.author;
        this.price = book.price;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Book other = (Book) obj;
        if (isbn == null) {
            if (other.isbn != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!isbn.equals(other.isbn))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    // getters, setters and hashcode omitted
}
```

**BookRepository**:

```java
public class BookRepository {
    private Map<String, Book> books;

    public BookRepository() {
        books = new HashMap<String, Book>();
    }

    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        return new ArrayList<Book>(books.values());
    }

    public Book getBook(String isbn) {
        if (books.containsKey(isbn))
            return new Book(books.get(isbn));

        return null;
    }

    public boolean addBook(Book book) {
        Book copy = new Book(book);

        if (!books.containsKey(copy.getIsbn()))
            return books.put(copy.getIsbn(), copy) == null;

        return false;
    }

    public boolean deleteBook(String isbn) {
        return books.remove(isbn) != null;
    }

    public boolean updateBook(Book book) {
        Book copy = new Book(book);

        if (books.containsKey(copy.getIsbn()))
            return books.put(copy.getIsbn(), copy) != null;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! You should consider accepting an answer, or if none are okay with you, post a comment or edit your question telling us why ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code based on the [answer of Antot](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/166072/71678) and the [answer of Ronan Dhellemmes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/166014/71678). Because performance it not an issue, I'm not going to use an additional list to improve speed as described in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/166013/71678).

### Book

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Book {

    private final String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private double price;

    public Book(String isbn, String title, String author, double price) throws InvalidBookException {
        if (isbn == null)
            throw new InvalidBookException("ISBN cannot be null.");
        if (isbn.isEmpty())
            throw new InvalidBookException("ISBN cannot be an empty string.");

        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Book(Book book) {
        this(book.isbn, book.title, book.author, book.price);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Book [isbn=%s, title=%s, author=%s, price=%s]", isbn, title, author, price);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(this.isbn);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Book other = (Book) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.isbn, other.isbn);
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

### BookRepository

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class BookRepository {

    private Map<String, Book> books;

    public BookRepository() {
        this.books = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Book get(String isbn) {
        Book copy = null;

        if (this.books.containsKey(isbn))
            copy = new Book(this.books.get(isbn));

        return copy;
    }

    public boolean add(Book book) {
        Book copy = new Book(book);
        return this.books.putIfAbsent(copy.getIsbn(), copy) == null;
    }

    public boolean remove(String isbn) {
        return this.books.remove(isbn) != null;
    }

    public boolean update(Book book) {
        Book copy = new Book(book);
        return this.books.computeIfPresent(copy.getIsbn(), (isbn, existing) -> copy) != null;
    }

    public List<Book> getAll() {
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Book book : this.books.values())
            list.add(new Book(book));

        return list;
    }

    public void removeAll() {
        this.books.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nice and the only advice I can give you is this: `getAllBooks()` may be improved from linear to constant time.

Consider

```
public boolean addBook(Book book) {
    Book copy = new Book(book);

    if (!books.containsKey(copy.getIsbn())) {
        this.list.add(book);
        return books.put(copy.getIsbn(), copy) == null;
    }

    return false;
}

public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.list);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! But I found a new problem: When I get a list by `getAllBooks()` I can modify a _internal_ book: `bookRepo.getAllBooks.get(0).setISBN("123")`. Do I need to create a new list and copy over all books?

Answer (score 1):

The code is good overall ^^

If you are worried about the `Map` key being out of sync with the `Book` it references, why not just make sure ISBN can't be changed inside `Book` ? It doesn't make much sense to have a setter about this anyway, IMO.

Also, once a model object is created, it's usually a good idea to make sure it doesn't contain any illegal value (so in your case, a negative price, a `null` author or an invalid ISBN for example).
Since you have *setters*, you should put the code that check for correctness in the *setters* and simply calls the *setters* from your constructor.

Checking for ISBN in your `Book` constructor may be a pain however, so I'd create a new `ISBN` class that would represent a correct ISBN and which is immutable.

Some books have more than one authors, something you should consider.

With all above proposals, the `Book` class may look like this :

```
public class Book {
    private final ISBN isbn;
    private String title;
    private Collection<String> authors;
    private double price;

    public Book(final ISBN isbn, final String title, final String author, final double price) {
        this(isbn, title, Collections.singleton(author), price);
    }

    public Book(final ISBN isbn, final String title,
                final Collection<String> authors, final double price) {
        this.isbn = Objects.requireNonNull(isbn);
        setTitle(title);
        setAuthors(authors);
        setPrice(price);
    }

    public Book(final Book book) {
        this.isbn = book.isbn;
        this.title = book.title;
        this.authors = new ArrayList<>(book.authors);
        this.price = book.price;
    }

    public ISBN getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Collection<String> getAuthors() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(authors);
    }

    public void setTitle(final String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthors(final Collection<String> authors) {
        if (authors.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("authors must not be empty");
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    public void setPrice(final double price) {
        if (price < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("price must be positive");
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Book other = (Book) obj;
        return isbn.equals(obj.getIsbn());
    }

    // a few getters and hashcode omitted, consider also adding a nice toString ^^
}

public class ISBN implements Serializable, Comparable<ISBN> {
    private final String isbn;

    public ISBN(final String isbn) {
        // check for isbn correctness here !
    }

    // rest of the code, make sure this is an immutable object and that the equals method is correct !
}
```

I removed the test for ISBN nullity in the `equals` method, simply cuz now it's impossible to have a `null` field (ignoring reflexivity, but if someone use reflexivity to mess with your objects internal and invariants, it's their own problem :))

Your repository object is really good looking :) Only thing is, if you apply the previous advices, you don't need to make copy of the book everytime :)

**[EDIT]** : completely forgot to add something about the *price*, storing price in double is usually a bad idea, consider reading : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285680/representing-monetary-values-in-java

Answer (score 1):

### Book

1) Use constructors chaining:

```
public Book(Book book) {
  this(book.isbn, book.title, book.author, book.price);
}
```

2) Implement `Cloneable` instead of creating an instance of `Book` from another. Calls of `new Book(book)` will thus be replaces with `book.clone();`

3) Do not check for strict class equality in `equals`, but use `instanceof`:

```
if (!(getClass() instanceof Book)) {
  return false;
}
```

With strict class equality, if another entity inherits from `Book`, it would fail to call `super.equals(obj)` and violate the principle of implementation.

4) Simplify `equals`:

```
if (isbn == null) {
  if (other.isbn != null)
    return false;
} else if (!isbn.equals(other.isbn))
  return false;
return true;
```

This complexity is easily avoided with a single call:

```
return Objects.equals(this.isbn, other.isbn);
```

5) As already mentioned in another post, do not use `double` for prices.

### BookRepository

1) `books` map should be `final`.

2) In `getBook`, instead of checking two times in the map, one call could be enough:

```
public Book getBook(String isbn) {
  final Book book = books.get(isbn);
  if (book != null) {
    return book.clone();
  }
  return null;
}
```

3) `addBook` can be reformulated with already existing API method:

```
public boolean addBook(Book book) {
  return books.putIfAbsent(book.getIsbn(), book.clone()) == null;
}
```

4) Idem for `updateBook`:

```
public boolean updateBook(Book book) {
  return books.computeIfPresent(book.getIsbn(), 
                                (key, oldBook) -> book.clone()) != null;
}
```

5) There should be a bit of non-null validation of `book` args in `add` and `update` methods.

Comment: Hi ! I completely agree with everything you said for `BookRepository` but I disagree with points 2 and 3 for `Book`. `clone` is considered bad practice by some people (Josh Blosh included which is clearly not your average java dev) so you should at least mention it. Using `instanceof` in equals brings as many problems to the table than it solves : if you have a subclass `A` of `Book` and `A` have its own fields then you can have `bookObject.equals(a) != a.equals(bookObject)`... while IMO `instanceof` makes more sense here, the problems that arise for its use should be pointed off ^^